# How do we add a file folder in our machine to a GitHub repository using SourceTree?

Tags: github, atlassian-sourcetree

I am trying to link a folder in my own machine with a GitHub repository using SourceTree. I am new to these sort of technologies, so I might be making mistakes.

I had been searching inside out but I could not find a proper tutorial or a source that can help me. Can someone help me with this along with the proper steps to achieve this task?

Comment: I'm installing sourcetree at the moment to see if I can help you. Did you create a new, empty repository on GitHub? Do you have any files in the local folder already?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new local repository based on an existing remote repository is calld **cloning**.  Look for the Clone button.

Answer (score 0):

As @Colin suggested, you can **clone** a repository from GitHub.

In SourceTree do the following

**Source Path**: Your GitHub repo path

**Destination Path**: Local folder path where you want the repo to be downloaded

**Bookmark Name**: Put anything here, this would be the title of the repo in SourceTree
[image: SourceTree Clone Repo]

or if you happen to create a repository first on your local machine and then later create it on GitHub, you should add a remote URL to your local repo by doing

> git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git

You may want to look at Git tutorial https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/